# Usage of /tags/{tag}/top-answerers/{period}

Tags: support, api

[API docs](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/top-answerers-on-tags) says,

> Returns the **top 30 answerers** active in a single tag, of either all-time or the last 30 days.

and I can only get [`top 20`](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/top-answerers-on-tags#tag=javascript&period=all_time&filter=default&site=stackoverflow&run=true) Why?

Is there a way to get top 50 tag answerers?

Comment: The API message is probably incorrect; the tag top users pages on the site also only ever show 20 users. I've mixed up the 30 a few times myself (30 **days**, not 30 **users**).

Comment: @MartijnPieters tnx for response; so there is no other way to go beyond 20 users?

Comment: No, the server calculates these once every 24 hours, and only publishes the top 20 then.

Comment: @MartijnPieters this is very unfortunate in case you would like to check on competition. :)

Comment: Bug reported: [top-answerers / top-askers documentation bug: number of results returned incorrect](http://stackapps.com/q/4735)

Comment: Simple: answer better than [Miller on `perl` questions](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/perl/topusers), all the time. :-P

Comment: @MartijnPieters it is a shame that API does not provide such feature.

Comment: You can make that a feature request on [StackApps.com](http://stackapps.com) and see if it is implemented.

Answer (score 1):

This was fixed in 2019. The docs now state you only get the top 20, which is consistent with what you see on the site.

Status completed in [top-answerers / top-askers documentation bug: number of results returned incorrect](https://stackapps.com/questions/4735)